# How can I make perf script -g python work?

Tags: python, performance

After installing `perf` with the `linux-tools-common` package, I still can't use the python/perl scripting abilities.

```
$ sudo perf script -g python
Python scripting not supported.  Install libpython and rebuild perf to enable it.
For example:
  # apt-get install python-dev (ubuntu)
  # yum install python-devel (Fedora)
  etc.
```

How can I install a perf version with scripting support, in Ubuntu?

Comment: I was just googling for an answer myself and came across this question.  I'd like to extract each and every captured callstack.

Comment: @Will extracting callstacks is possible even without scripting support. The easiest way is `perf report --stdio`.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the call sacks in the raw output aren't annotated with function and library names.  I've been trying to work it out by also looking at the MMAP events etc.  Just not easy.

Comment: @Will if you don't have symbol information `perf script` won't help you here. Try installing debuginfo packages for relevant programs, see also http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2014-09-11/perf-kernel-line-tracing.html

Comment: Yes yes yes.  When I use the standard perf reports I get symbol information; when I look at the raw dump the symbols aren't resolved.

Comment: @Will, erm, it makes sense, doesn't it. Raw dump should be raw, and not parse symbols. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to count how many inter-library calls there are in average call stacks.  Perf -g gives me good call stack snapshot samples, so I can run representative programs and get perf.data.  However, the report tools all seem to summarise, although they do have library and function columns, and I want the raw call stacks.  I was hoping perf script would let me see them annotated, as looking at the raw dump doesn't do symbol resolution for me nor tell me which lib each call is in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since *Raring* (13.04), `perf` is built without Python scripting enabled “to avoid a Python build dependency”. This came as a nasty shock to people like me who used `perf` in 12.04 LTS and upgraded to 14.04 LTS. This is documented in the [`debian-master/changelog` file](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git?p=ubuntu/ubuntu-trusty.git;a=blob;f=debian.master/changelog;h=ea6704d97abbd667b5cd722da82df9edf66ca906;hb=HEAD) in the Ubuntu kernel git repos.

In short, if your kernel is 3.8.0-6.11 or later, you are — to use the precise technical terminology — “shit outta luck”: you have to build your own `perf`.

If you decide to do this the Ubuntu way, which is actually quite easy, you can google for tutorials with varying levels of detail (e.g. [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel) or [here](http://blog.avirtualhome.com/compile-mainline-kernel-ubuntu/)). Once you have reached the stage where you have cloned the Ubuntu kernel `git` repo appropriate to your release and have checked out the tag corresponding to your current kernel (if your current kernel is 3.13.0-48-generic, the tag will be something like `3.13.0-48.80`, i.e. with an extra number on the end), you must edit (w.r.t the root of the `git` repo) `debian/rules.d/2-binary-arch.mk` and *remove* `NO_LIBPYTHON=1` from one of the `make` command-lines (it's used in `\#ifdef` checks, so changing it to `NO_LIBPYTHON=0` won't work). This clause only appears once, so just search for it and take it out.

The distro's `linux-tools-3.x.x-y` package contains the actual `perf` binary, which ends up in `/usr/lib/linux-tools-3.x.x-y/perf`. This is built with `fakeroot debian/rules binary-arch`. This rule (`binary-arch`) takes a long time to build (~25 mins on my i7 laptop). If I'd paid more attention, I could probably have picked one that didn't build every kernel variant and module. Suggestions welcome.

Assuming that you've made no other changes, once this finishes, **the package you want is `linux-tools-3.13.0-48_3.13.0-48.80_amd64.deb`** (modulo your kernel version): this is the one with the binary, rather than symlinks or shell wrappers.

There may be a couple of other `linux-tools` packages, depending on exactly what you've built, `linux-tools-3.13.0-48-generic_3.13.0-48.80_amd64.deb` just contains symlinks and stuff (less likely to be different) and `linux-tools-common_3.13.0-48.80_all.deb` just contains the short generic `perf` wrapper script that ends up in `/usr/bin`; the latter is built with `fakeroot debian/rules binary-indep`.

You can install your new Python-capable `perf` with

```
# sudo dpkg -i linux-tools-3.13.0-48_3.13.0-48.80_amd64.deb
```

You can install as much, or as little, of the kernel, kernel modules, other tools packages, etc. as you're comfortable with. In principle, these should all be the same. I just installed the one package and everything seems to work OK: I have my Python-capable `perf` back.

Of course, you're going to have to do a lot of this again (from a `git pull` and `checkout` of the new tag onward) next time there's a kernel update. I'll have to keep up with this myself, so I was half-thinking of sticking my .debs into a PPA, but there doesn't seem to be much interest (this question upvoted twice in 3 months).